# how to replace a char in string with many chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date

I want to change a char in string with many values

I have string like this :

```
date_format = "%m/%d/%Y";
```

And i want to replace ever % with the char which after, so the date variable should be like this:

```
date_format="mm/dd/YY";
```

Here is what I tried so far, but i can't get it to work, so I need some help here:

```
function replaceon(str, index, chr) {
    if (index > str.length - 1) return str;
    return str.substr(0, index) + chr + str.substr(index + 1);
}

function locations(substring, string) {
    var a = [],
        i = -1;
    while ((i = string.indexOf(substring, i + 1)) >= 0) a.push(i);
    return a;
}

function corrent_format(date_format) {
    var my_locations = locations('%', date_format);
    console.log(my_locations.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < my_locations.length; i++) {
        replaceon(date_format, my_locations[i], date_format[my_locations[i] + 1]);
    }
    return date_format;
}

console.log(corrent_format(date_format));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that:

```js
var date_format="%m/%d/%Y";
var res = date_format.replace(/%(.)/g, "$1$1");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
"%m/%d/%Y".replace(/%([^%])/g,"$1$1")
```

Hope this hepls.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function act(str) {
  var res = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < (str.length - 1); i++) {
    if (str[i] === "%")
      res += str[i + 1];
    else
      res += str[i];
  }
  res += str[i];
  return res;
}
var date_format = "%m/%d/%Y";
console.log(act(date_format));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because the `date_format` variable is not being modified by the `corrent_format` function. The `replaceon` function returns a new string. If you assign the result to `date_format`, you should get the expected result:

```
for (var i = 0; i < my_locations.length; i++) {
  date_format = replaceon(date_format, my_locations[i], date_format[my_locations[i]+1])
}
```

Alternatively, you could perform the replacement using [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and a regular expression:

```
date_format.replace(/%(.)/g, '$1$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

For the regex-challenged among us, here's a translation of `/%(.)/g, '$1$1'`:

- `/` means that the next part is going to be regex.
- `%` find a `%`.
- `.` any single character, so `%.` would match %m, %d, and/or %Y.
- `(.)` putting it in parens means to capture the value to use later on.
- `/g` get all the matches in the source string (instead of just the first one).
- `?1` references the value we captured before in `(.)`.
- `?1?1` repeat the captured value twice.

So, replace every `%.` with whatever's in the `.`, times two.

Now, this regex expression is the most concise and quickest way to do the job at hand.  But maybe you can't use regular expressions.  Maybe you have a dyslexic boss who has outlawed their use. (Dyslexia and regex are uneasy companions at best.)  Maybe you haven't put in the 47 hours screaming at regular expressions that aren't doing what you want, that you're required to put in before you're allowed to use them.  Or maybe you just hate regular expressions.

If any of these apply, you can also do this:

```
var x = '%m/%d/%y';
x = x.replace('%', 'm');
x = x.replace('%', 'd');
x = x.replace('%', 'y');
alert(x);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the `replace` function only replaces the first match found.

But seriously, don't use this.  Use regex.  It's always better to invest that 20 hours working out a regex expression that condenses the 20 lines of code you wrote in 15 minutes down to one.  Unless you have to get it done sometime tonight, and whatever you're trying just doesn't work, and it's getting close to midnight, and you're getting tired...well, no.  Use regex.  Really.  Resist the temptation to avoid finding a regex solution.  You'll be glad you did when you wake up at your desk in the morning, having missed your deadline, and get to go home and spend more time with your family, courtesy of your generous severance package.

Comment: All kidding aside, I use regex wherever I can, especially if i can swipe something that someone else has already written.